# Redirect to other page on alert box confirm

Tags: javascript

This is a piece of my function with **the question** in it:

```
function deletePost() {
    var ask = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this post?");
    if (ask) {
        window.alert("This post was successfully deleted.");

        /* How to redirect to another page on confirm? */

    }
}
```

Pure Javascript needed.

Comment: Have you searched the Google for "javascript redirect"?

Comment: Yes, but the ways showed there doesn't work for me. @McMaster already helped me with an answer below.

Comment: The first two search results contain exactly same code.

Comment: Search results in Google are persolnalized. Personalization is based on information that they steal from your computer, when observing your behavior... Be patient and watch your hands ;)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

try this:

```
function deletePost() {
    var ask = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this post?");
    if (ask) {
        window.alert("This post was successfully deleted.");

        window.location.href = "window-location.html";

    }
}
```

Comment: This worked, I've tried to redirect by this way: `window.location = "http://link.com"`, and this did not work. Thank you.

Comment: Perfect, I had an almost identical problem and this also saved me.  Why won't the other two options work?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript

Comment: those 2 answers on the link work just fine.. my `document` should be `window` though (amazing what i missed a year ago).. this function shows a confirmation of an action then redirects to specific location.. redirects can be achieved several ways, the above is just one..