# Redirect to another page using javascript without query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, redirect

I want to redirect to another page and pass some parameters only using javascript. I am not supposed to use query string. Is there any way to achieve this? I am working on asp.net.

I want this redirection to use with devexpress scheduler control where when a user clicks on an appointment, the user be redirected to another page by passing the selected appointment's ID as parameter. It should not be passed as query string.

I would also like to know how to retrieve such kind of invisible parameter from the redirected page.

Ok I found out my solution.

I used javascript to click a `<asp:Button>` that is set to `style="display:none"`. In my scenario, I could get the properties of scheduler appointment that I had clicked. I then put these properties in hidden fields and in the server side click event of this 'invisible' button, I use these hidden field values to make my redirection through server side. My code is as below

```
<asp:Button ID="Appointment" runat="server" Text="sample" 
    onclick="Appointment_Click" style="display:none"/>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfID" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfSubject" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfDate" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function OnAppointmentClick(s, e) {
        //debugger;
        var apt = scheduler.GetAppointmentById(e.appointmentId);

        var apt1 = scheduler.GetAppointmentProperties(e.appointmentId);

        var aptID = document.getElementById('<%= hfID.ClientID %>');
        var aptDate = document.getElementById('<%= hfDate.ClientID %>');
        var aptSubject = document.getElementById('<%= hfSubject.ClientID %>');
        aptID.value = e.appointmentId;
        var date = (apt.startDate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + apt.startDate.getDate() + '/' + apt.startDate.getYear(); 
        aptDate.value = date;
        aptSubject.value = apt.CODE;
        document.getElementById('<%= Appointment.ClientID %>').click();
    }    
    </script>
```

Comment: Is this your homework ? :)

Comment: No. This is my office work. I am working with devexpress scheduler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**ASP.net Code:**

```
Response.Headers.Add("id", "testtest");
Response.Redirect("http://www.somesite.com/somepage.aspx");
```

**Java Script Code:**

```
window.location = 'http://www.somesite.com/somepage.aspx?q=manvswild';
```

**jQuery Code:**

```
var url = "http://www.somesite.com/somepage.aspx?q=manvswild";
$(location).attr('href',url);
```

**jQuery Ajax Code:**

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'page.aspx',
    data : {
        paramname1 : "put_param_value_here",
        paramname2 : "put_param_value_here",
        paramname3 : "put_param_value_here"
    },
    dataType : 'html',
    success : function (e) {
        window.location = e;
    }
});
```

**// or short method is**

```
$.post("page.aspx", {
    param1 : 'one',
    param2 : 'two'
}, function (data) {
    window.location = data;
});
```

**jQuery plugin:** http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object

```
alert($.query.set("section", 5).set("action", "do").toString());
```

Output:

```
?section=5&action=do
```

Comment: Your answer is quite good one but I am not allowed to use query string due to security reasons.

Comment: @Nisha: Then try to manipulate with session in aspx. use session to pass param or you can use encrypt/decrypt with your secure data. Good Luck!!

Answer (score 1):

try this 
document.location.href = "window-location.html"

already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591953/redirect-to-other-page-on-alert-box-confirm)

Comment: Sorry, but the link you provided does not talk about passing parameters.